# Select the next select box beside a td and then select an option by its text value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-select2

In short, I need to automate selecting a dropdown value from a webform. I've tried using:

```
$("td:contains(Gender)")
    .closest('td')
    .next()
    .find('select')
    .filter(function () { return $(this).html() == "Female"; })
    .val();
```

(just do see if I could return anything and it said undefined)

And

```
    $("td:contains(Gender)")
    .closest('td')
    .next()
    .find('select')
    .find('option:contains(Female)')
    .attr('selected', true)
```

(but this would require nested find() to work

The HTML Looks like:

```
<html>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Gender:</td>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option>Male</option>
                <option>Female</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</html>
```

The short of it is I cannot use ID's or classes due to the "unique" way the webform is built. I also am aware that I probably cannot use contains due to male and female both containing "male". The values in the dropdowns are all numerical so I'd prefer if I could use text instead of mapping the values.

If you're wondering I am an automation engineer so I've no control over the form itself.

Kind Regards,
K

Comment: What do you want the output to be?

Comment: Hi, I want to set the value selected in the dropdown to Female

Comment: Yea check my answer below

Comment: I need a coffee, didn't realise you were the same person...thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost correct, you just not need to call `.closest('td')` as `$("td:contains(Gender)")` will return the jQuery object of `td` itself.

```js
$("td:contains(Gender)")
    .next()
    .find('select')
    .find('option:contains(Female)')
    .attr('selected', true)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Gender:</td>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option>Male</option>
                <option>Female</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks that's exactly it! I actually tried that already but it the select2 dropdown did not display the selected value until after I saved!